# Custom script results in Call to a member function on null

Tags: magento-1.9, module, development

I use the following script to update the stock levels of products from a csv. Worked well until recently, where I created a custom observer where I am checking if the product save occurred in the admin product edit page. Now, the script returns the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFullActionName() on null

Why would this be happening when it should be able to do this?

**The Script**

```
 <?php
 define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__DIR__)));
 require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

 umask(0);
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 $count = 0;

 $file = fopen(MAGENTO . '/apiscripts/tstt.csv', 'r');
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { 

 if ($count == 0) {
 foreach ($line as $key=>$value) {
 $cols[$value] = $key;
 } 
 } 

 $count++;

 if ($count == 1) continue;

 #Convert the lines to cols 
 if ($count > 0) { 
 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 unset(${$col});
 ${$col} = $line[$value];
 } 
 }

 // Check if SKU exists
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 

 if ( $product ) {

 $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
 $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
 $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
 $stock = array();

 if (!$stockItemId) {
 $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
 $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1); 
 } else {
 $stock = $stockItem->getData();
 }

 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 $stock[$col] = $line[$value];
 } 

 foreach($stock as $field => $value) {
 $stockItem->setData($field, $value?$value:0);
 }


 $stockItem->save();

 unset($stockItem);
 unset($product);
 echo "<br />Stock updated $sku";
 }
 }
 fclose($file);

?>
```

**Snippet of the observer**

```
$actionInstance = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if ($actionInstance == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_save') {  ...}
```

**The full observer code**

```
    public function saveStockItemAfter($observer)
{
    $actionInstance = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if ($actionInstance == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_save') {    
           $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
           $custReason = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('stock_change_reason');

        if (!$stockItem->getStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag() && $stockItem->getOriginalInventoryQty() != $stockItem->getQty()) {
            if (!$message = $stockItem->getSaveMovementMessage()) {
                    if (Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->getSessionId()) {
                        $message = sprintf('Stock saved from Magento API%s', $this->_getStockReason($custReason) ?': '.$this->_getStockReason($custReason):'');
                    } else {
                        $message = sprintf('Manual Save%s', $this->_getStockReason($custReason) ?': '.$this->_getStockReason($custReason):'');
                    }
                }
                $this->insertStockMovement($stockItem, $message);
            }           
    }
}
```

**CSV**

[image]

Comment: which event you are using for observer ?

Comment: @Pawan cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after

Comment: you can use `catalog_product_save_after` event and get the product data in observer.

Comment: @Pawan interesting, but what would be the benefit of using this over the current event?

Comment: `catalog_product_save_after` will work when product will save and `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` will fire when inventory will update.So may be earlier one can work in any update to product.

Comment: @Pawan the custom observer will check for inventory changes, so current event is more suitable.

Comment: could you share 3-4 sample row of CSV ?

Comment: See update for csv

Comment: I tried your code with CSV. When we are saving product from admin observer is working but during script run it is not working. I think there is no `action` available during script run

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your observer isn't setup correctly. You should be getting the full action name from the observer object instead of instantiating `Mage:app()`

Ex.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function beforeProductSave($observer) {
        $actionInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();

        if ($actionInstance == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_save') {
            // Product was saved from admin
            // Add any additional code here
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you're passing an $observer object as a parameter to your observer method. The name $observer is arbitrary but standard practice.

Comment: The observer is working well bar the script. Where the error is occurring. Trying to get the action name from the observer event gets `Call to a member function getFullActionName() on null` even on admin product save.

Comment: I have added my full observer code above